# Bezier Curve Assistance

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, bezier

I'm trying to take my Bezier Curve and add more curve in the center (see pic). 
[image]

Currently, my bezier curve is less curvy. I've tried messing around with all of the various numbers, but I'm not getting anywhere. Please see my fiddle-file: http://jsfiddle.net/FVU47/

Relevant code:

```
var rect1 = {
  x: 103,
  y: 262,
  w: 200,
  h: 100,
};

var rect2 = {
  x: 484,
  y: 170,
  w: 200,
  h: 100,
}

function drawBezier() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(rect2.x + rect2.w/2, rect2.y + rect2.h/2);
  context.bezierCurveTo(434,314,354,218, rect1.x+rect1.w/2, rect1.y +rect1.h/2);
  context.lineWidth = 20;
  context.strokeStyle = 'white';
  context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, as per @Isotropix thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, if you want such shape for bezier curves you should not use center of rectangles but first retrieve which side(edge) of rectangle are facing (connected), in your example above, it's Box1' right edge connected to Box2 left edge. After that, use center of edge as start/end points of bezier curve, intermediate points may be added depending on connected edge (maybe different if a right edge is connected to a left or a top/bottom edge).

Comment: ...And you can increase the "curviness" by making the control points closer to the opposing rectangle. ;-)